# Receiving data from Scanner via serial port

Tags: serial-port, barcode-scanner, ept

I want to receive data from a scanner through a serial port.
My scanner is connected to a EPT (Electronic Paiment Terminal) on COM0.

The scanner seems to work fine, I can detect barcodes and QrCodes but nothing is received on serial PORT.
Every scanner I tried ended with the same result, but I managed to receive data from other devices.

Is there any specificities about that kind of devices ?

On EPT side, serial port is formated as the scanner dialog (115200, 8, N, 1 with no flow control)
I can receive data from the scanner to a computer and from computer to the EPT.

I have tried with two different scanner:
    - HoneyWell 3310G
    - Posline PS-75

I work on a IWL250 and a IUC180B. Both are EPT made by INGENICO. Both react in the same way.

On EPT, I have to use a C API given by the constructor of the machine.

Below my test code :

```c
if(IsCOM0()){

    if(stdcom0() == 0)
        hCom0 = Telium_Fopen("COM0", "rw");
    else
        hCom0 = stdcom0();

    Telium_Format("COM0", 115200, 8, 1, NO_PARITY, EVEN, 0);
    Telium_Send_receive(hCom0, ON, ON);
    iRet = Telium_Ttestall(COM0, 0);
    iRet = Telium_Ttestall(COM0, 0);

    do{

        j = Telium_Fread(&test[i++], 1, 1, hCom0);

    }while(j > 0);

    Telium_Fclose(hCom0);
}
```

With every devices except the scanner i have, Telium_Ttestall detect an event on COM0 and I can read data in &test.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To get answers and advice, you should have more detailed information. For example, the manufacturer of the scanner, model number, specification document, EPT manufacturer, model number, specification document, OS type and version number, etc. Also, describe the relevant part of the program source used for reading with EPT.

Comment: Thank you for the advice i have updated my post

Comment: When searching with Telium_Fopen and Terium_Fread, the following source code was found. It might be helpful for some usage. [MayBank mayb_workflows Src external_scanner_capture.cpp](https://git.paysys.com.my/swadhin097/MayBank/blob/2d19ee2ff6d3c50f705e281705530ad4bd199ac4/mayb_workflows/Src/external_scanner_capture.cpp), [MayBank mayb_security Src load_master_key.cpp](https://git.paysys.com.my/swadhin097/MayBank/blob/1b79ecb62d77aedf843237eef4e0b2eea33902f6/mayb_security/Src/load_master_key.cpp)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot access your links, server does not respond

Comment: Now, I couldn't access it as well. It may have been a private source. I feel like I saw the name of INGENICO in the header, so there may be a similar sample in the SDK of your EPT. Please look for it.

Comment: You're right, there are samples in SDK but nothing specific with scanner and I'm already in contact with they're software development support. I was just wondering if anyone have already had a similar issue with that kind of devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind,

We have solved the issue. The wire we were using was not made correctly.
Sorry for disturbing.

Best Regards,